# Google App Engine remote_api for sharing user accounts across apps

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a site that has multiple sub-domains, each for a separate app. The trick is, I want the users to be defined in one place. To do this, my plan was to have the naked domain or the www sub-domain basically be a dashboard app and that is where the users would be created and stored.

The other apps that are served from the sub-domains would then need to be able to query the dashboard app's datastore for authentication. The sub-domain apps would still use their own data store for all of their respective entities.

So my question is, can you use remote_api or some other tool to programatically, from within an app, connect to another app's datastore like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good use for the new modules feature.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

But if you don't want to use modules you'll need to create web services for communicating between apps.